# Skype Online Presence not showing in document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Having an issue with the online presence skype box that appears next to a user's name in Sharepoint 2016. For 25% of the users, it displays the correct status and can pull up the skype profile card. For 75% of the users, it is blank, "presence unknown",  and the skype card that pulls up says "Stmp@[OurEmailDomain].com"

Weirdly enough, the search page displays ALL Skype profiles/status correctly. I can see the correct status/profile of a person, but when I open the document library or list associated with the search result, it is again the non-working profile.

Working/Non-working Profiles have remained consistent, and are the same for different users and computers. I've also combed through the ProxyAddresses attribute for working/non-working profiles, each one does contain an sip address, and there does not seem to be a pattern of commonality between working/non-working profiles.

It worked correctly in SP2010

I've tried disabling-renabling Person Name Actions and Online Presence Settings in general settings in Central Admin, no luck.

Any ideas? Thanks for reading,
-Mark